# How to run pip from python3.7.1

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having python3.7.1 installed on my Mac, but when I run the command pip --version it shows syntax error. It's said that for python3 and greater versions pip is pre-installed, but why still I'm not able to use pip from python3?

Comment: What is the exact error? MacOS comes with python2.7 by default, pip will usually be for python2.7. You should use pip3 for python3+

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that instead, I've installed the python 3.7.1 in my mac and also I've updated my pip. Both is successfully installed, now I want to run Django from python3, so I want to open pip in python3. Now I want to run pip from python3, how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Open? Pip is a Python Package Installer. To install package you can use ```pip3 install yourPackage```

Comment: Let me make things bit clear. I want to run Django in python3, so how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

pip might be outdated, check for updates running this command on terminal in your Mac:

```
pip install -U pip
```

Also doble check the version you have by running:

```
python --version
```

if you get

> “Python is not defined”

you will need to reinstall it.

Further reading: [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)

Comment: Hi Hasan, Thanks. My python version is python 3.7.1 and I've even updated pip to latest version. Can you please tell me now how to run pip from python3 shell?